# Запуск программы jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Господа, добрый день.

Помогите пожалуйста, проблема такая. Я установил анаконду, все вроде нажал, как в установщике. Потом нажимаю на иконку юпитер из меня пуск и мне выходит такое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И дальше в браузере не загружается, я делал, как он предлагает через локалхост и вбивания руками токена он открывает, но это не реально делать постоянно  и глупо совершенно. Подскажите плз ,как сделать, чтобы он сам сразу в браузере открывался.

Comment: `jupyter notebook --generate-config` запускали?

Comment: я честно скажу чайник, подскажите это в командной строке запускать? @vp_arth